# Accessing specific occurances of comments in XML using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML, and I want to find all the elements within the comments which are bold(second occurrence of the comment).

For that, I have written a xpath:

Type/a/b[@Name='FULLTEXT']/comment()[contains(.,'START OF CUSTOMIZATIONS')]/following::*[not(preceding::comment()[contains(.,'END OF CUSTOMIZATIONS')])]

But, somehow it is not working. Any idea what is wrong in xpath?

```
<Type>
    <a>
        <!--START OF CUSTOMIZATIONS-->
        <c />
        <!--END OF CUSTOMIZATIONS-->
        <b Name="FULLTEXT">
             <c />
             <c />
             <c />
             <c />
             <c />

             **<!--START OF CUSTOMIZATIONS-->
             <c />
             <c />
             <c />
             <!--END OF CUSTOMIZATIONS-->**
             <c />
        </b>
    </a>
</Type>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `following-sibling` and `preceding-sibling` instead of just `following` and `preceding` (wrapped for readability):

```
Type/a/b[@Name='FULLTEXT']
/comment()[contains(.,'START OF CUSTOMIZATIONS')]
/following-sibling::*[not(preceding-sibling::comment()[contains(.,'END OF CUSTOMIZATIONS')])]
```

by using `not(preceding-sibling::comment()[contains(.,'END OF CUSTOMIZATIONS')])` all `c` elements will be filtered out because they all has such preceding comment node, which is the first occurrence of `<!--END OF CUSTOMIZATIONS-->`.